# Facebook app on canvas: change content with JS

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, innerhtml

I have been trying to modify DIVs on a canvas app on Facebook with JavaScript, but it doesnt work nor does it throw an error. I have been trying to use innerHTML and FB's setInnerHTML, to no avail.

Has anybody faced this situation or know what to do? Here is the code that doesnt do a thing:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setId("someNewId");
div.setInnerFBML("<p>dynamically added stuff</p>");
document.getElementById("someDivId").appendChild(div);

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "someNewId";
div.innerFBML = "<p>dynamically added stuff</p>";
document.getElementById("someDivId").appendChild(div);
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know very much about the Facebook syntax, but it could be a typo: In your question you use `innerHTML` and `setInnerHTML`, but in your code you have `innerFBML` and `setInnerFBML`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: the typo is actually in my example really, i copied quickly to be able to ask my question. thanks for pointing it out, it could have been that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Facebook has announced that they are deprecating FBML (http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap).

Since you are building a new app, you would want to choose IFrame instead of FBML - and if you are using IFrame, all the javascripts would run just fine, and you don't have to mess with any of this FBJS stuff.  You can write any javascript that would normally work in a browser and even use mootools, jQuery, or any other javascript libraries.

Comment: That is an interesting take, I'll try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yup, this was the best way for me to get the stuff and to be able to work in a (semi) normal workflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting this code? FBJS doesn't allow JavaScript to be executed until a user has interacted. Try running the function on an onclick.

Also if you're using firebug, console.log works

Comment: i was actually calling this on a onclick function indeed.